# stalling and jerking

Tags: electrical, kia, sedona

2006 KIA Sedona just spent over a $1000 and still not repaired. When coming to a stop it stalls or in some cases almost stalls and when accelerating reaching 35 to 40 mph it starts to jerk but just slowing down a bit and it runs normally.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Is the check engine light on?

Comment: no but it does come on when it stalls stopping